# Prototypes of objects within objects

Tags: javascript, function, prototype, this

I'm trying to make a function that can be applied to a value returned from another function both within a function. Since that's probably a terrible explanation, here's a simplified sample:

```
function MainFnc() {
    this.subFnc=function(a) {
        return a*2
    }
    this.subFnc.subSubFnc=function(a) {
        return this*a
    }
}
```

This isn't my actual code - it's for a far better reason than multiplying numbers. This is just a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve. My question is whether or not it's actually possible to go this deep, and if so how? The method I've portrayed in this sample code evidently does not work.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Here's an example of it in use since not everyone understands clearly what I want to do with this:

```
anObject=new MainFnc;
alert(anObject.subFnc(2)); //returns 4
alert(anObject.subFnc(2).subSubFnc(2); //returns 8
```

This is **not** exactly what I'm doing, it's just easier to understand using simple multiplication.

Comment: Can you post a more succinct example of what you're trying to do?  As it is, it looks like you're trying to call `(new MainFnc()).subFnc.subSubFnc()`, but I don't see a reason behind why you're trying to do that (e.g. there's nothing tying anything together)

Comment: MainFnc is an object which is created in a variable (ie MainVar). So if I wanted to try MainVar.subFnc(2) it'd return 4. If I wanted to try MainVar.subFnc(2).subSubFnc(2), however, it'd return 8. Do remember that this is a simpler version of my actual code, which is far more complex. What I want to achieve is more clearly portrayed using simply multiplication.

Comment: Still don't understand what you mean when you say you want to alter the data returned by one?  Your example can be accomplished with the answer I posted, but I don't think it's what you want

Comment: `(new MainFnc()).subFnc(2)` would return 4, so I wanted it to be possible to optionally add `.subSubFnc()` to further modify the value returned, in this case changing 4 to 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** based on your comment:

> `MainFnc` is an object which is created in a variable (ie `MainVar`). So if I wanted to try `MainVar.subFnc(2)` it'd return `4`. If I wanted to try `MainVar.subFnc(2).subSubFnc(2)`, however, it'd return `8`.

Right now, you're returning a number from your `subFnc`, and so the expression `MainVar.subFnc(2).subSubFnc(2)` breaks down like this:

1. Look up the property `subFnc` on `MainVar`; it returns a function reference.
2. Call the function with `this` = `MainVar`; this returns the number `2`.
3. Look up the property `subSubFnc` on the number `2`; it returns `undefined`.
4. Call the function with `this` = `2`; fails because you can't call `undefined` as a function.

More: [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html) and [*Mythical Methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)

To do what you're doing, you'd have to have `subFnc` return an object with function properties. You could do it like this:

```
function MainFnc(val) {
    this.value = val;

    this.mult=function(a) {
        return new MainFnc(this.value * a);
    };

    this.div=function(a) {
        return new MainFnc(this.value / a);
    };

    this.get = function() {
        return this.value;
    };
}
```

...and then call it like this:

```
var MainVar = new MainFnc(3);
alert(MainVar.mult(3).mult(4).div(6).get()); // alerts "6" (3 * 3 * 4 / 6 = 6)
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/opamu4/2)

Note the `get` function to return the underlying number. You might also add a `toString`:

```
this.toString = function() {
    return String(this.value);
};
```

But the above isn't taking advantage of prototypical inheritance at all (and it will be important to, if you're creating all of those objects; we need to keep them lightweight); you might consider:

```
function MainFnc(val) {
    this.value = val;
}
MainFnc.prototype.mult = function(a) {
    return new MainFnc(this.value * a);
};
MainFnc.prototype.div = function(a) {
    return new MainFnc(this.value / a);
};
MainFnc.prototype.get = function() {
    return this.value;
};
MainFnc.prototype.toString = function() {
    return String(this.value);
};
```

---

**Original Answer**:

With that code, if you did this:

```
var f = new MainFnc();
alert(f.subFnc(3));           // alerts "6"
alert(f.subFnc.subSubFnc(3)); // NaN
```

...because `this` inside `subSubFnc` when called like that is `subFnc`, and multipling a function reference tries to convert it to a number, which comes out `NaN`, and so the result of the multiplication is `NaN`.

Remember that in JavaScript, `this` is defined entirely by *how a function is called*, not *where the function is defined*. When you call a function via dotted notation (`a.b();`), the object you're looking up the property on becomes `this` within the function call, and so with `a.b.c();`, `this` within `c()` is `b`, not `a`. More: [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html) and [*Mythical Methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)

Comment: Honestly, you kinda confused me. From my interpretation, it looks like you're saying that `this` in subSubFnc would be the whole subFnc itself, right? Would that mean that what I'm trying to achieve is actually impossible? Or is there a way to do this with what subFnc returns?

Comment: @Jimmy: *"...it looks like you're saying that this in subSubFnc would be the whole subFnc itself, right?"* It would be defined the way you defined it and called as I showed, but now that I understand your ultimate goal from your comment on the question, I've updated to show you how to do it. It is possible. :-)

Comment: You removed subSubFnc in this update, though. In my actual script, subSubFnc modifies the className of an element created with subFnc. The two aren't as similar as portrayed in the sample function I made up.

Comment: @Jimmy: True, but you can always have multiple functions on `MainFnc`. The basic principle the above demonstrates is *chaining*, the ability to call functions on the result of the previous function. I had another thought, but it was (mostly) specific to numbers; from your comment, that would be off-topic so I'll leave it there... Best,

Comment: @Jimmy: Added a second function that does something different. Best,

Comment: It looks like what I need now. I honestly don't have time to test it, but from thoroughly reading over your modified answer it looks much like what I was asking for. Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: @Jimmy: No worries, glad that was useful. Do look at @cwolves' answer as well, some good points in there.

Answer (score 2):

This is about as close as you can get:

```
function foo(n){
    this.value = n;

    return this;
};

foo.prototype = {
    valueOf : function(){
        return this.value;
    },
    multiplyBy : function(n){
        return new foo(this.value * n);
    }
};

foo.prototype.toString = foo.prototype.valueOf;

var x = new foo(2);
var y = x.multiplyBy(2).multiplyBy(2).multiplyBy(2);

// y == 16
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to add multilevel prototypes so that I can alter the data returned from one optionally. See my comment on the OP for an example; I'll edit it into the OP.

Comment: @Jimmy: FWIW, "OP" is usually used here (and elsewhere) to mean "original poster" (the person originally posting a question -- e.g., you), not "original problem" as you seem to be using it above.

Comment: I used it as Original Post. It seems synonymous.

Comment: @Jimmy - not entirely, "OP" means you as a person, you're using it to mean the question you wrote

Comment: Updated my answer, that's about as good as you can get in JavaScript